# LDAP Connection using app pool identity

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, ldap

How do I connect AD with LDAPConnection using application pool identity in asp.net.

Application is loading user details from AD using LDAP Connection. To connect with AD currently the user name and password is stored in the web.config and we are using the below code to connect with AD

```
// Create an LDAP connection to the server
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(ldapServerName);
NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domainName);
connection.Bind(networkCredential);
```

Instead of using credential from web.config how do I use ASP.Net Application pool identity for connecting AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(ldapServerName);
connection.SessionOptions.Sealing = true; // Using Kerberos 
connection.SessionOptions.Signing = true; // Using Kerberos 
connection.Bind(CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
```